# Pointer created then set equal to an index in an array but getting different values

Tags: c++, c++14

Created an array of type RectangleShape in SFML and created a pointer of Rectangle shape using the 'new' keyword then set the index of the array equal to the value of the pointer. When I want to get information such as position and I then move the shape and then call it's getPosistion() function, I only get the values of where I originally called it but when I call it from the index in the array, i get the updated coordinates.

```
head = new RectangleShape();
head->setPosition(250, 250);
snake = new RectangleShape[_size]; //_size is set to 10 
snake[0] = *head;
//do some movement to the object via calling 
snake[0].move(...);

//then calling the positions
cout << "head: " << head->getPosition().x << " , " << head->getPosition().y << endl;

cout << "snake[0]: " << snake[0].getPosition().x << " , " << 
snake[0].getPosition().y << endl;
//I will only get the correct position from calling snake[0] but not  head->...
```

Comment: *created a pointer of Rectangle shape using the 'new' keyword* -- Why are you using `new` at all?  I see no reason for it in the example you posted.  Also `std::vector` is the "dynamic array" in C++.

Answer (score 3):

`snake[0]` is distinct object, originally initialized as a copy of `*head`. After that, the two are independent and unrelated.

Comment: And is there a way for me to just get snake[0] to just be a reference to the value that head points to?

Comment: `head = &snake[0];`, I suppose. It's not quite clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I was trying to make snake[0] and *head be references to the same RectangleShape object

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `new` performs two operations: **allocation** and **initialization**.

When you call `new RectancleShape()` it will first **allocate** memory on the heap to hold one instance of `RectangleShape` and then invoke the constructor to **initialize** that memory.

When you call `new RectangleShape[_size]` it will allocate memory on the heap to hold `_size` instances of `RectangleShape` and initialize them with the default constructor.

In your scenario, you do not want to be doing both of those allocations. You either want to allocate the memory in the array, or you want to allocate and initialize each instance individually and then store the pointers in an array.

Instead of allocating a new instance and pointing `head` to it, first allocate the array then point `head` to the first element of `snake`.